# Windows Installation

Tags: mlpack

I'm trying to setup `mlpack` on my Windows 10 machine for development. The instructions seem to be pretty old. The `mlpack` version currently available is mlpack-3.2.2.

The folder structure seems totally different in this version. For example, there's no **packages** directory anywhere.

I have Visual Studio 2019 and would like to be able to do development in it.

Can someone share the latest instructions on setting up
`mlpack`?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation has improved lately. Just follow the steps of the official [tutorial](https://www.mlpack.org/doc/mlpack-git/doxygen/build_windows.html) as they are listed.
This worked for me, for both mlpack-3.2.2 and the more recent mlpack-3.4.x.

Suggestion: if you decide to use the Cmake GUI, remember to let the include path of the Armadillo library point to its "build" folder (to be clear the folder where you create the solution which you later build to get armadillo.lib) or it won't find it when you push the "Generate" button.